# SPA is not working in online hositng

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I recently published my SPA to the free account of hostinger.in. In localhost the application works fine. But in online account it not loading views and producing errors in console mentioned bellow.

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mdm.890m.com' is therefore not allowed access."

PLese help me to solve the issue!

Comment: Please do a search for that error. It is  CORS problem and there are thousands of similar posts here as well as lots of documentation on the web

Comment: this is not the reply i asked for...i am a newbee, hence this is kind a heart breaking

Comment: Well you are expected to do basic research yourself and this error is easy to research. Understand your frustration but search the web first before asking here so you at least understand what it means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative path in your templateUrls are wrong in app.js Please remove the "mdm" directory from your template urls. So templateUrl: '/mdm/html/fundtype.html' becomes templateUrl: '/html/fundtype.html'

Also the error output is misleading in this case, as your host does a 302 redirect to a 404 page on a different host, causing the CORS error. This is not a CORS problem because your initial request is for the same host.

Comment: This is awesome! You made my day. What a help to a newbie.